# TFS 2013 api - get email alert message id

Tags: api, tfs, alert

Is there a possibility to get the message id of the work item alert using API?

Comment: What do you mean by "message ID"?

Comment: I meant e-mail messageID ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message-ID ).But probably i need to tell more about what i would like to do. I'm looking for a relation between the work item and the email alert about this work item, which was sent to somebody. I would like to get the message of that email via API if this is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to get the message ID. There is no record of the sent email kept. This is consistent with expectation